# função document.write não escreve duas mensagens

Tags: javascript

Iniciei a um mês e meio os estudos e o pequeno código abaixo **não está escrevendo o nome e os pontos dos dois times informados, apenas de um.** Se retiro do código a escrita dos dados do primeiro time ele exibe o resultado do segundo normalmente. Também substituí o document.write na função 'mostra' pelo console.log e no console exibe os resultados dos dois times normalmente. Li em alguns artigos uma informação que o método document.write apaga as informações anteriores, mas não entendi como isso funciona. Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço.

```
    <script>

        function pulaLinha () {
            document.write ("<br");
        }

        function mostra (frase) {
            document.write (frase);
            pulaLinha ();
        }

        function perguntaJogosECalcRes (nomTime) {
            var vit = prompt ("Quantos jogos o time " + nomTime + " venceu?");
            var emp = prompt ("Quantos jogos o time " + nomTime + " empatou?");
            var pontos = (vit * 3) + parseInt (emp, 10);
            return pontos;
        }

        var nomTime1 = prompt ("Qual o nome do primeiro time?");
        var nomTime2 = prompt ("Qual o nome do segundo time?");

        var ponTime1 = perguntaJogosECalcRes (nomTime1);
        var ponTime2 = perguntaJogosECalcRes (nomTime2);

        mostra (nomTime1 + " " + ponTime1);
        mostra (nomTime2 + " " + ponTime2);

    </script>
```

Comment: `document.write ("<br");` <- falta aqui um `>`

Answer (score 4):

A função document.write é cheia de peculiaridades. Por exemplo, ela faz coisas diferentes enquanto o documento está carregando e depois de ele terminar de carregar.

Se você quiser imprimir umas coisas pra fim de debugação, é melhor usar `console.log`

Se você quiser mostrar algo pro usuário, use os métodos do DOM:

```
function mostra(frase)
    var span = document.createElement("div");
    var text = document.createTextNode(frase);
    span.appendChild(text);

    document.body.appendChild(span);
}
```